# bash command to check if line has certain pattern

Tags: bash

I have a file in which I have to check a line that begins with a certain pattern. for example - id: 34. I wrote bash script but it does not seem to detect the line

```
#!/bin/bash

id=34

# Read the file line by line
while read line; do
  # Check if the line starts with pattern
  if [[ $line =~ ^[[:space:]]-[[:space:]]id:[[:space:]]$id ]]; then
    in_section=true
    echo "$line"
  fi

done < file.txt
```

sample file

```
$cat file.txt 
apiVersion: v1
data:
  topologydata: |
    config:
      topology:
        spspan:
        - id: 1
          name: hyudcda1-
          siteids:
          - 34
        spssite:
        - id: 34
          location: PCW
          matesite: tesan
```

Comment: You are only matching a line that starts with *one* whitespace charcter, not an arbitrary sequence of whitespace. Presumably, that line is not indented with a single tab character.

Comment: Save yourself a lot of trouble, and use a proper YAML parser instead of trying to hack something together with regular expressions.

Comment: to use yaml parsing was my first thought but trust me I dont have that option

Comment: As @chepner said, you are matching only one unit of whitespace.  If you use "*" it will match zero or more, like this `if [[ $line =~ ^[[:space:]]*-[[:space:]]*+id:[[:space:]]*+$id ]]; then`

Comment: `read` trims whitespace from the beginning and end of the line; to get the *whole* line, use `IFS= read -r`.

Comment: Note that your question is specifically about lines in a file, with YAML I would do something along `yq -r '.data.topologydata' inputfile | yq '.config.topology | to_entries[] | select(.value[0].id == 34)'`

Answer (score 1):

You was close, but better use `grep`:

```
grep -E "^[[:space:]]+-[[:space:]]+id:[[:space:]]+$id" file
```

And you should give a try to a YAML parser: [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/)

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression matches exactly one single space before the `-` character while `read` removes the leading and trailing spaces, so your `$line` variable value has zero leading spaces. Try:

```
^[[:space:]]*-[[:space:]]id:[[:space:]]$id
```

It will match with zero or any number of leading spaces. If you can also have zero or more than one space between `-` and `id` and between `id` and the integer, try:

```
^[[:space:]]*-[[:space:]]*id:[[:space:]]*$id
```

And if you want `read` to keep the leading spaces try:

```
while IFS= read line; do
```

Finally if, instead of zero or more, you want to match **one** or more spaces replace `*` by `+`.